# mpdf Merge two pdfs to one page

Tags: php, mpdf

Hello I have a array of pdfs (format A5), and i want a merge all into one pdf-file, but on the one page (A4) i need two pdfs (format5). Is it possible? This code is merge all files to one, but every file on a single page, thanks for optimize.

```
                $filenames = [
                    '01.pdf',
                    '02.pdf',
                    '03.pdf',
                ];

                $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
                    'format'            => 'A4-L',
                ]);
                $filesTotal = sizeof($filenames);
                $mpdf->SetImportUse();   

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($filenames); $i++) {
                    $curFile = $filenames[$i];
                    if (file_exists($curFile)){
                        $pageCount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($curFile);
                        for ($p = 1; $p <= $pageCount; $p++) {
                            $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($p);
                            $wh = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($tplId);                
                            if ($p == 1){
                                $mpdf->state = 0;
                                $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
                            }
                            else {
                                $mpdf->state = 1;
                                $mpdf->AddPage($wh['w']>$wh['h']?'L':'P');
                                $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);    
                            }
                        }
                        unlink($curFile);
                    }           
                }                
                $mpdf->Output('all-mergered.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: See https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples/blob/development/example44_MPDFI_yearbook.php, should help.

Comment: Or examples #40 and #43 in the same repository.